# read a list of integers from another function and then square it

Tags: list, erlang

I want to build a function called `Square(N)`. This function will take a list of integers that comes from a previous function that I have built, and then it will return the list of integers it received, only each number is now squared.

So if the read list is `[1,2,3,4]` then it should return `[1,4,9,16]`. My function is as follows:

```
Square(N) when N > 0 -> Square(digitize(N));
Square([]) -> [];
Square([H|T]) -> [H*H|Square(T)].
```

And if you wonder what `digitize(N)` does, it reads in any number and then displays each digit of that number into a list. The digitize function is as follows:

```
digitize(N) when N < 10 -> [N];
digitize(N) -> digitize(N div 10)++[N rem 10].
```

The result I got when compiling the function is an error:

> `an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you pass N (integer) to the digitize function it returns a list. so you can't pass the returned list back to the same function and compare it to integer zero. you should break up the square function so it calls the another function example square_list to deal with the list returned from the digitize function. see example below.

```
square(N) when N > 0 -> square_list(digitize(N)).

square_list([]) -> [];
square_list([H|T]) -> [H*H|square_list(T)].

digitize(N) when N < 10 -> [N];
digitize(N) -> digitize(N div 10)++[N rem 10].
```